# Proving $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^x = \infty$

Tags: calculus

I need to prove this limit with epsilon-delta definition, and here's what I got

Let $M > 0$ be given. We want to find $N > 0$ s.t if $x > N$, then $e^x > M$

From $x > N, $

$e^x > e^N = M$.  Choose $N =\ln(M)$.

However, the answer seems to be $N= \min(\ln (M), 1)$

Why does this happen?

Comment: If $M<1$ then $\ln(M)<0$, so if we choose $N=\ln(M)$ we haven't found $N>0$

Answer (score 1):

$N$ should be chosen to be $N=\max(1,\ln (M))$ rather than the minimum.

This way, just as it is stated in the comment, $N$ is ensure to be positive even when $M$ is less than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $N: \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by $N(M) \equiv \max(1, \lceil \ln M \rceil)$.  Then for all $M>0$ we have:

$$e^n \geqslant e^{\max(1, \lceil \ln M \rceil)} \geqslant e^{\ln M} \geqslant M
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } n \geqslant N(M).$$

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following definition of $e^x$

- $e^x = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left( 1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$

you can proceed as follows:

- Bernoulli-inequality gives for $x>0$: $e^x \geq 1+n\cdot \frac{x}{n} = 1+ x$

The same inequality also follows for $x>0$ immediately from the series definition of $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} \geq 1+x$.

Anyway, for $M> 1$ choose $N =M-1$. So, you get for $x>N$
$$e^x \geq 1+x > 1+N = M$$